# How to prevent jQuery sortable stop event from being cached

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my PHP backend I provided a way to sort all articles for a page.
I use twitter-bootstrap and so I made each `<div class="col-md-4>` sortable. The articles are wrapped inside panels which are the sortable items.

I bound the stop event of the sortable to a function that lets a button appear that says "Apply Sorting". The idea is to be able to shuffle articles as often as needed and then click on the "Apply Sorting" button to run a single ajax call to PHP which updates the sorting field for each article.

This is my code:

```
    // cols are all bootstrap column divs
    cols.sortable({
      items: '.panel-default',
      delay: 50,
      cancel: ".adder",
      beforeStop: function() {
         cols.sortable('refreshPositions');
      },
      stop: addSortButton,
     });

     function addSortButton() {
      // if button exists do not add another one
       var button = $('.sorter');
       if (button.length === 0) {
          $('.seperate').prepend('<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary sorter">Apply Sorting</button>');
       }
       $('.sorter').one('click', function(e) {
          applySorting();
       });
     };

     function applySorting() {
        var articles = cols.find('article');
        var holder = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
            var sorting = i + 1;
            $(articles[i]).attr('data-sorting', sorting);
            var id = $(articles[i]).attr('data-id');
            holder[id] = sorting;
        }
        $('.sorter').prepend(spinner);
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/admin/nodes/sort',
           data: {
             'values': holder
           },
        }).done(function(msg) {
            $('.sorter').html('Apply Sorting');
            if (msg === 'ok') {
               alert('Sorting update ran successful!');
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {

       });
     };
```

**My problem is:**
For example when I only move one article one ajax call is made. which is fine. But when I decide to move more articles and maybe switch 4 of them to different locations I get **4 ajax calls**. I thought I could prevent this behavior by the jQuery one() function but it is not working. Also the berforeStop event has no effect trying to clear that.

Comment: Your title is *"how to prevent jquery sortable stop event from being cached"* I don't understand any caching issue from your description..??

Comment: Where are you removing the existing buttons...??

Comment: The button is injected with text "Apply Sorting", why are you again setting the same thing with `$('.sorter').html('Apply Sorting');`..?

Comment: What if the user doesn't click this button...?

Comment: The "Apply Sorting" button is only added to the dom when articles have been sorted. With caching i mean that each sorting action is somehow stored and then for each action a ajax call is made.

Comment: This is just to get rid of the spinning gif that is inserted during the ajax call.
When you dont click that button nothing is happening sorting stays the same which it is supposed to

Comment: That's because you have so many buttons that you haven't cleaned up. `.one()` only fires once, but after some sorts you have many elements in dom to which you are attaching that one time event. Each of them will fire once. Next time you're again attaching a one time handler to all buttons

Comment: Yes. the solution is probably to totally unbind the reading of the sorting attributes from the sortable. By having a button that is not bound to any sortable event.

Comment: having a static button or injecting the button and removing it properly before injecting another will do.

Comment: could you provide an example of injecting and removing it properly ? got it working now with a static button, but it would be more elegant to have that button only appear when sorting was made.